Is it possible to use the cisco webdialer service without sending the password in the soap message?
I am implementing webdialer in an java web app, according to cisco either you send a sso token or you send the user+pass in the soap message, i can't implement sso, and for user+pass every , the problem is that every time the user is going to make a call in the call screen he has to enter the pass, I thought about storing the password in the session (when he enters the pass for the first time), this way the user doesn't have to enter the password all the time and then destroy the password when the user exits the call screen, but storing the pass in the session seems a bit dangerous to me...any ideas for improvement?
store the pass in the session....
